# Whats the difference in const pointer and integer const pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

While reading tutorials regarding pointers, i faced a code like this

```
const int *p;
```

and

```
int const *p;
```

and

```
int *const p;
```

Whats the main difference in them?

While i assigned any integer value's address,like

```
int b=100;
b=&p;
```

i am getting errors. Whats the point in this? Can anybody explain it with example?

Comment: Try any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=const+before+after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, simply read it from right to left.

```
int const *p;
```

"`p` is a pointer to a `const` `int`".

```
int *const p;
```

"`p` is a `const` pointer to an `int`".

The exception is when `const` is the lefmost keyword:

```
const int *p;
```

Then it's the same as:

```
int const *p;
```

---

If the pointer is `const`, then you can't modify its address, but you can change the value pointed by it. If the pointed to value is `const` (an `int` in your case), then you can't modify what's pointed to by the pointer (but you can make it point to something else).

As an unrelated thing, this fails to compile:

```
int b=100;
b=&p;
```

Because you're assigning the address of the pointer veriable (a `int **`) to `b`. It's an illegal conversion. You could force it with a cast, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Assuming the variable naming is consistent, `b = &p;` should fail because we are assigning the address of a pointer (i.e. a pointer) to an integer, no?

Comment: @undur Indeed. Man, I must have been tired to not see that!